# What is the impact of stress on the human body?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, stress

Can stress trigger any changes in the human body? I'd like to know more about things less commonly known than, for example: sweating and tiredness. What are the long term risks of chronic stress? Do stressful people have higher chance of having heart-diseases or affected by hair-loss, for example?
I'm also interested in how can an emotion induce physiological changes in our body?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! Could you be more specific on your question, please? In this form I'm afraid this is too broad. Please visit http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour or http://biology.stackexchange.com/help sites for help on asking on-topic questions.

Comment: @I don't know - After your editing the question got better, yet I thought it's still too borad / unclear, so I took the liberty and reformulated so I can be reopened. I did this because in my opinion the question itself hold potential. To be honest I tried to keep as much of the original meaning / intention as possible, and it may still qualify as too broad. You can undo my editing if you wish to revert it back to your original edited form. I'm also voting for reopening this question.

Answer (score 1):

Stress is the reaction, which our body reacts against the pressure or tension. There are many impact of stress on the human body, which includes

- Emotional:  Moodiness, short temper, agitation, inability to relax, feeling lonely and always depressed.
- Cognitive:  Memory problems, unable to concentrate, very poor judgment, negative thoughts, always anxious and worrying
- Physical: Frequently suffering from pains and aches
- Behavior: Addiction toward drugs, alcohol or cigarettes for relief, nervous, being alone, insomnia.
- Other problems like headache, muscle pain, chest pain, fatigue, etc.

Comment: Hello Ravi. Can you add some references to support your answer?